# why there is the factor $n$ in the RHS of the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality for matrices?

Tags: real-analysis, matrices, analysis, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

In the book of *Analysis on Manifolds* by Munkres, at page 64, it is given that

$$|x_0-x_1| = |E^{-1} \cdot (E\cdot x_0 - E \cdot x_1 )| \leq n |E^{-1}| \cdot |E\cdot x_0 - E \cdot x_1|.$$

I can see that the author uses the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality, but I cannot understand **why there is the factor $n$ in the RHS ?** I mean he multiplies the dimension the matrix in such inequalities all the time, so I figured it should be a term in the matrix version of Cauchy-Schwartz inequality.

Comment: What is $|E^{-1}|$? The determinant?

Comment: @JefferyOpoku-Mensah No idea.

Comment: @JefferyOpoku-Mensah Munkres defines $|A|$ as $\max|a_{ij}|$.

Comment: If it is the matrix norm, try looking [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1767993/matrix-norm-inequality-proof-does-this-use-cauchy-schwarz)

Comment: Schwarz not Schwartz !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out: Theorem 1.3, page 5.